# Zurb's Foundation 4: How to use block grid to distribute groups of pre/postfix fields?

Tags: forms, zurb-foundation

I'm dynamically creating forms that will have an unknown number of semantically-related text-fields that must share a row (in [Foundation's](http://foundation.zurb.com/) sense of the word) and be distributed evenly within it. The blockgrid class seems the better option, but I can't get the pre and post fix classes to work within it.

*Note: this isn't my actual code, but rather a generalized form of the problem to increase community utility*

```
<ul class="large-block-grid-<? echo count($choices);?> row"> <!-- $choices = array of fields--> 
    <h6><span data-tooltip class="has-tip" title="">TooltipText</span></h6>
    <li class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <label for="inputA">
                <input type="text" id="inputA" name="inputA" placeholder="val" />
            </label>
        </div>
         <div class="small-3 columns">
            <span class="postfix radius">PostFix Label A</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <label for="inputB">
                <input type="text" id="inputB" name="inputB" placeholder="val" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-3 columns">
            <span class="postfix radius">PostFix Label B</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I end up with postifixes that are taller than their corresponding fields and problems with the left margins/padding (see screen cap). Anyone?

[image: screen cap of my problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I figured out my issues. Description of solution first, then the (slightly) improved code below:

1) the `<ul>` element isn't a row in Zurb's sense, and applying the "row" class was buggering up the margins; it should have been *in* one.

2) left align was broken because block-grids should, it turns out, be nested inside the usual grid; adding a wrapping `<div>` with a n-column class fixed it.

3) can't wrap `<input>` in `<label>` tags if it is to be paired with a postfix (this is what causes the height problems on the postfix `<span>`; may just be that I can't have the field nested inside a [block-level](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) element at a different level than the `<span>` element it's paired with; I just deleted the `<label>` elements and was happy enough to have resolved the problem).

The code:

```
<!-- note that I've now wrapped everything in a column-classed div -->
<div class='large-12 columns'>
<ul class='large-block-grid-*'> <!-- * = php's count on an array of fields--> 
    <h6><span data-tooltip class='has-tip' title="">TooltipText</span></h6>
    <li class='row collapse'>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
            <input type='text' id='inputA' name='inputA' placeholder='val' />
        </div>
         <div class="small-3 columns">
            <span class='postfix radius'>PostFix Label A</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class='row collapse'>
        <div class="small-9 columns">
                <input type='text' id='inputB' name='inputB' placeholder='val' />
        </div>
        <div class="small-3 columns">
            <span class='postfix radius'>PostFix Label B</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```